# Making higher amperes using the DC volts?

Tags: voltage, converter, amperage

I have hear, but am not certain that this is true because I find it impossible( I'm only a junior in highschool been working that electronics with my teacher for about 4 years) but anyway, supposally you can turn 10v 1A into 5v 5A by making small changes to your circuit( values might not b accurate ). I believe that this is cause by hooking two chips( unknown) improperly and that's what you get.
I do not know much about it but I'm sure someone does and I'm sure thousands of people would love to know this so please give me some help finding how to do this.
 I believe this is not caused by a coil, transformer or anything like that.

Comment: If you don't have the time to write out full words I will certainly not have the time to write answers.

Comment: 10V at 1A is 10W. 5V at 5A is 25W. That violates conservation of energy (unless you add another source), so it's clearly impossible.

Comment: If it is impossible then thank you for letting me now.but again my changes might not b right, it is just an example bc I don't know how this works. All I really now about it is that it turns the voltage into current

Comment: Energy conversion can never be more than 100% efficient. Watts are an energy unit and conversion always consumes something. So watts out will always be less than watts in for ANY energy conversion device. If anyone tells you otherwise they are trying to sell you snake oil.

Answer (score 2):

10V and 1A is ten watts and this is a continuous power. If you choose to store energy (power x time) in a large capacitor then you can certainly extract 10V and 5A (50 watts) for a short period of time but you can't convert a continuous input power of 10 watts into a continuous output power of anything greater than 10 watts.

Basically, ignoring conversion inefficiencies, 10 watts continuous can be made to be 20 watts but for only 50% of the time. It can be made into 100 watts but for only 10% of the time. Are you getting it yet?

Answer (score 1):

It is imposible to turn 10 V 1 A into 5 V 5 A. 5 V and less than 2 A is possible, but not more than that.

Comment: Ok well can u explain to me how to do this?

Comment: @user100476 - Explain how to do what? You've been told a number of times already that the premise of your question is impossible to do.

Comment: Simple, a buck converter can do this. Find a module based on the LM2596 chip on ebay (for example), they are cheap and these can convert 10 V into 5 V. If you load the 5 V with 2 A, the 10V side will be loaded by about 1 A (a little more due to conversion losses). 100% efficiency is impossible but if you find a way, please let us know.